# How to execute Cloud Composer DAG with some runtime parameters from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I'm looking for an example to kick off a Cloud Composer DAG execution from Cloud Function. I also want to pass some variables from Cloud Function. Those variables have to be used in the Python code for creating DAG.

Please help me with some reference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more information about the usage of Cloud Functions for event-based DAG triggers, I recommend you to read this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf#triggering-with-gcf-creating-a-function-python). It explains all the steps to set up the Cloud Function.

Reading the instruction in above link, there is a topic *"Creating your function"*, there you can see an example how to create the **main.py** and the **requeriments.txt** files. In addition, you can also see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing) for further explanation about writing a Cloud Function.

There are also [sample codes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/composer/rest) for Composer on GitHub which might be helpful for you to kick off.

Lastly, I would like for you to pay attention whether you installed the python dependencies and connect Cloud Composer to other environments, see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies) for more details.

**UPDATE:**

Regards passing parameters from Cloud Function to DAG, it depends which parameters you want to pass as a variable. According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags#bashoperator), you can pass varibales as execution date or file name as variables. It could be as follows for filename:

1. input_file = ‘{{ dag_run.conf["name"] }} ‘
2. Then within your BashOperator set “bash_command=’echo ‘+input_file)”
3. Set up the dag_run.conf “name” field ⇒ gcloud beta composer environments run myenvironment --location=europe-west1 trigger_dag -- -c '{"name": "Hello World"}' myDAG

I would encourage you to read about [Jinja Template](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html#default-variables) and Also [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/python.html)(also [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#xcoms) for PythonOperator). In addition, there is a [context dict](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html) which helps accessing variables from Airflow.

Comment: I see there is an option to trigger a Cloud Composer DAG from Cloud Function but apparently there is no coverage on how to pass variables from Cloud Function to Cloud Composer DAG. Do you have any such reference?

Comment: I am going through the documentation to find out if it is possible. I will be back to you soon.

Comment: @BalajeeVenkatesh, if you want to pass the file_name or execution date, for instance, as a parameter to be accessible in DAG, you can use the  BashOperator. The bash_command template is a template. I hjave updated the answer with some useful links and an example. I hope it helps.